# angular ng-class does not react on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I am trying to use ng-class and bind a class to an expression so, that I can unit test the expression binding. But, it seems that I am missing something.

The button:

```
<li><a class=""  ng-click="onAddInterface()"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> add interface </a></li>
```

The panel that should collapse and expand:

```
<div class="collapse" ng-class="{in:showCreateNewInterfacePanel}"><div>
```

the function that is fired

```
$scope.onAddInterface=function(){
  $scope.showCreateNewInterfacePanel=true;
}
```

anyway clicking the link nothing happens.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How could we know if you're missing something without seeing all of the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is how you are really defining your `$scope.onAddInterface` function or if it is just an example... Nevertheless you should be doing it like this:

```
$scope.onAddInterface = function() {
  $scope.showCreateNewInterfacePanel = true;
}
```

**update**

Also make sure the link and the collapsible element are under the same $scope/Controller:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  ...
  <a ng-click="onAddInterface()">add interface</a>
  ...
  <div class="collapse" ng-class="{in:showCreateNewInterfacePanel}"><div>
  ...
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.onAddInterface = function() {
    $scope.showCreateNewInterfacePanel = true;
  }
}​
```

Comment: Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/H2Qcn/),with only @bmleite's change.  This fiddle shows that class "in" is being applied when you click.  If it still doesn't work for you, then there may be something wrong with the CSS (not Angular).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it still does not work, tried with simpler custom css and it still not working !!!!!!!!

Comment: Are sure the link is accessing the correct $scope? Does your `onAddInterface` function ever get called? Can you provide a bigger snippet from the HTML you are really using?

Comment: Yes, the problem was in the scope. would you mention it in your answer to accept it as the best answer ? the problem was that the collapsible  element was out of the scope of the controller :)

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar problem and was able to solve this problem by placing 'in' in quotes.  It is a string, and not a variable.

```
  ...
  <div class="collapse" ng-class="{'in':showCreateNewInterfacePanel}"><div>
  ...
```